# download a large size project from maven repository

Tags: maven, findbugs

my professor have assigned me to download a large size project from Maven repository and then run it through findbugs to report errors, if any.

I have installed Maven and started creating a simple project but I need to download an existence project in maven so is there any help on how I can download a large project from maven?

Comment: The question's a bit unclear. Do you want help finding an interesting external project (probably off topic), or with the procedures for using Maven to get from an external repository (on topic, but what have you tried so far)? Please edit the question to clarify

Comment: I am new to maven so the assignment isn't clear to me too. Are there any projects stored in maven central repository?

Comment: I would suggest to ask your professor...which we are not...